# Assembly versioning for Webpart

Tags: 2013, feature-upgrade

I have already read many articles about feature versioning/upgrading but somehow I seem to be a blockhead at the moment.

My issue is that I do have a webpart which has some code behind which renders some data into the webpart. Lets say this is the version 1.0.0.0.

Now I would like to change the behavior of the webpart as I would like to display information from some additional lists. Therefore I would have to change the code behind file. My problem is that the additional information would only be available when the new version of the webpart is used.

So my question is how to keep the old assembly version of the code behind and only use the new version of the code behind after I have performed an "feature.upgrade()".

Somehow I cannot get my head around this. So any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible, all your code-behind files will be placed in the same DLL. And the only versioning you can do there is at the assembly level.

Comment: I was afraid of this answer. Is there way I can check the version information from within the code-behind?

Comment: Might need some tweeking but: Version version = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Version;

Comment: Sorry for my imprecise question. I meant if it is possible the feature version in which the web part is included. This was I would be to able make a way around this in the assembly checking for the version.

Comment: I guess if you know the ID and scope, you can search it up in the SPWeb.Features or SPSite.Features (depending on scope) and then use the SPFeature.Version property :)